# How to display carousel from folder using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to display pictures for a carousel from a folder. I have tried writing the code, but it just displays the first image.  I am new to PHP, so any help would be really appreciated.

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php

    $images = glob('dosc/*.jpg');

    foreach($images as $image)
    {
      echo '<div class="carousel-item active">';
      echo '<img class="d-block w-100"  src="'. $image .'" onclick="window.location.href = \'mainpage.html\';">';
      echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I personally think that this is far to vague of a question to receive a concrete answer. Could you provide more details? Perhaps more source code? Perhaps the folder structure of your project, etc.

Comment: `onclick="window.location.href = "mainpage.html";"` is using the double quotes wrong

Comment: This is all there is for the carousel. I will tell you my file structure though. All the images I need to put on the carousel will be in the dosc folder.

Comment: @kerbholz used escape characters to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: What's the exact problem with this code? Most probably, your problem does only cover PHP, HTML, **or** JS, but not all of them

Comment: @NicoHaase I ended up fixing the issue, i answered it below

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it, by just adding a flag variable, and resetting it after each loop, an idea I got from another post, but all is good now.

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">

    <?php

    $images = glob('dosc/*.jpg');
    $flag=1;

    foreach($images as $image)
    {
      echo '<div class="carousel-item' .($flag?' active':''). '">';
      echo '<img class="d-block w-100"  src="'. $image .'" onclick="window.location.href = \'mainpage.html\';">';
      echo '</div>';
      $flag=0;
    }
    ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```